# How in Elasticsearch set size of result of top_hits aggregation?

Tags: php, sql, elasticsearch, backend

This query returns 1 product from EACH category.

Please help me, how to set size of total products count returned by this aggregation? Is it possible?

Elasticsearch version = 5.6

```
"aggs": {
    "category": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "categoryID",
        "size": 100000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "products_from_all_categories": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "from":0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Each product has its own category_id. Top_hits returns me one product from each category.I need to limit the final aggregation to N products.

For example, now it returns:

```
[ 
{product_id: 344, category_id: 1}, 
{product_id: 522, category_id: 2}, 
{product_id: 822, category_id: 3},
...
{product_id: N, category_id: M}

]
```

I need to set, for example, size: 2, and get:

```
[
{product_id: 344, category_id: 1}, 
{product_id: 522, category_id: 2} 
]
```

Probably this can be solved with some kind of "kludge" aggregation, that will return the same products, while limiting by size... But which one?

Comment: What do you mean by **size of total products count returned by this aggregation**? Does total product count refer to the number of unique `categoryId` ?

Comment: @ESCoder, Each product has its own category_id. Top_hits returns me one product from each category.I need to limit the final aggregation to N products.
For example, now it returns:
[
  {product_id: 344,
  category_id: 1},
{product_id: 522,
  category_id: 2},
{product_id: 1122,
  category_id: 3}
]
I need to set, for example, size 2, and get:
[
  {product_id: 344,
  category_id: 1},
{product_id: 522,
  category_id: 2}
]

Comment: @ESCoder 
Probably this can be solved with some kind of "kludge" aggregation, that will return the same products, while limiting by size... But which one?